# VLC player cannot read the stream broadcast set up by itself. What could go wrong?

Tags: vlc-media-player, video-streaming, rtsp

I'm trying to set up a H264-encoded stream on rtp over a local area network. Starting from setting up a source on localhost (127.0.0.1):

```
$ cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0:chroma=YUY2:width=640:height=480 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=h264}:rtp{dst=127.0.0.1,port=5600,sdp=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8080/test.sdp}' --no-audio

VLC media player 3.0.16 Vetinari (revision 3.0.13-8-g41878ff4f2)
[0000564a7ca67290] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[00007f6fcc0013d0] stream_out_rtp stream out: Consider passing --rtsp-host=IP on the command line instead.
[00007f6fbc001200] x264 encoder: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2

[00007f6fbc001200] x264 encoder: profile High, level 3.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit

[00007f6fbc001200] x264 encoder: using SAR=1/1

[00007f6fbc001200] x264 encoder: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2

[00007f6fbc001200] x264 encoder: profile High, level 3.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
```

When I try to connect to this stream with VLC player:

```
Media > Open Network Stream >

rtsp://127.0.0.1:8080/test.sdp
```

I got the following error:

```
[00007ff3e00015f0] satip stream error: Failed to setup RTSP session
```

I have 2 questions:

- What are the possible causes of this failure, and how to fix it?
- Delivering an rtp protocol definition over rtsp seems to be too complex, how can I do this over local file system? I've tried `sdp=file://~/tmp/test.sdp` and saw no sdp file being created.

Thanks a lot for your help!